# WCF authorization token with mixed clients

Tags: wcf, authorization, token

I am working on some WCF services for an application that are not only consumed by our web app but would also be consumable from our clients internal applications. Since we will not know what environment the clients internal apps could be in we are going to go the least common denominator route.

We will have an authentication service that will return a token, and that token will be passed as the first parameter of every method call. My issue is that I would like a clean way to examine the token without having to put the call to the token checking logic as the first line of code in each service method.

I looked at implementing a parameter inspector in the BeforeCall method and that worked great in my first proof of concept, but what I don't like is having to throw an exception to let the consumer know that the token is not valid. All of my methods will return a result that has at least 2 basic properties - success and a list of error messages. I would love to just return the inavlid token information as one of the result's error messages because to me, an invalid token is not an exception, it is a validation, but I do not see a clean way to accomplish this transparently.

I almost went for the return value the the parameter inspector's AfterCall method but that allows the method to execute.

So I think that i have 2 choices -
    1 - Put a token check call as the first line of each method which will populate my returning result object
    2 - Throw an exceptioon in the parameter inspector, which really isn't all that bad.

Has anybody found a good way to do this?

Thanks,
Paul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really think you should reconsider this approach. Every stack understands soap headers, even if the person is building XML strings themselves. Just don't do anying like message security and you should be ok as far as interop goes.

If you still want to go this route, you could probably just write a custom [`IParameterInspector`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.iparameterinspector.aspx) which you can attach to the services using a behavior. Then just override the BeforeCall method and check the token there.

Comment: Drew, thanks for your comment - on 2 fronts. I was wondering if I would be able to do something like a soap header with all client types. That was where I was wondering if I could get hosed. 2nd - as I mentioned in my question I did try the parameter inspector. Is the only way to indicate an invalid token to raise a fault exception? Thanks!

Comment: Yes a FaultException is the way to go here. You can't actually intercept the call/return a response through this extension point. If you wanted to do that you'd need to implement an IDispatchMessageInspector instead, but that's a little deeper into the stack and you would be responsible for message [de]serialization yourself. Not sure why throwing a FaultException wouldn't be the desired approach though since you need to communicate any authentication error back to your client as a fault anyway. If you want me to add some details on intercepting with IDispatchMessageInspector let me know.

Comment: Drew, I am open to suggestions here. I just hate throwing exceptions for something that isn't, exceptional or not unexpected or check for. That said, if you're telling me that the standard way of notifying something like a failed authorization check is through a fault, then I am on board. And now the parameter inspector is more appealing. Why would you suggest against it? And yes, I will take you up on your offer of explaining IDispatchMessageInspector, especially the part about being responsible for deserialization. Thanks, Paul.

Comment: Drew, I am trying to add soap headers when creating a proxy using "Add Web Reference" and I don't see how to add headers with this. It is fine with a straight WCF client. Do you know how to add headers for an asmx client to consume wcf services?